# WinRT 8.1 settings in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to open a settings view in a Caliburn.Micro WinRT 8.1 app using VS2013 RC, but I keep getting an unhandled exception when opening it with the following message:

*Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Could not parse the VisualElements from the app manifest.*

I can reproduce the issues with the following steps:

1. create a new Windows Store app from VS2013 RC using the Blank app template.
2. add Caliburn.Micro via NuGet.
3. in App.xaml, change the base class to caliburn:CaliburnApplication (the namespace is declared as xmlns:caliburn="using:Caliburn.Micro").
4. in App.xaml.cs, change the class like this (for the CM-based settings I follow http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/settings-caliburn)

Code below:

```
public sealed partial class App 
{
  private WinRTContainer _container;    

  public App()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void Configure()
  {
      _container = new WinRTContainer();
      _container.RegisterWinRTServices();

      _container.PerRequest<MainViewModel>();
      _container.PerRequest<SettingsViewModel>();

      ISettingsService settings = _container.RegisterSettingsService();
      settings.RegisterCommand<SettingsViewModel>("Test settings");
  }

  protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
  {
      var instance = _container.GetInstance(service, key);
      if (instance != null) return instance;
      throw new Exception("Could not locate any instances.");
  }

  protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
  {
      return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
  }

  protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
  {
      _container.BuildUp(instance);
  }

  protected override void PrepareViewFirst(Frame rootFrame)
  {
    _container.RegisterNavigationService(rootFrame);
  }

  protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
  {
    DisplayRootView<MainView>();
  }
}
```

1. Finally, create folders for Views and ViewModels in the solution add add to them the required items: MainViewModel, SettingsViewModel, MainView, SettingsView. The views just include a TextBlock with some text. MainViewModel derives from Screen, while SettingsViewModel derives from PropertyChangedBase. There is no relevant code in any of them.

When launching the app, I can see the main view; then I open the charms bar and click settings, and I find the label leading to my app settings; when I click it, I get the exception quoted above. Any hint?

You can find a full repro solution here: http://sdrv.ms/18GIMvB .

Comment: CM has not been updated to support Win8.1 yet and there are quite a few changes that will affect the framework (eg. Settings and `Flyouts` in general)

Comment: Thank you guys, so I think is just a matter of time to get this fixed.

Comment: Although it's not in the stable/current release, it looks like there is [Windows 8.1 support in the latest source](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#samples/Caliburn.Micro.HelloWinRT81/Caliburn.Micro.HelloWinRT81/App.xaml.cs) - I could put that as the answer?

Comment: The NuGet version (1.5.2) is still relying on Callisto flyout, but the latest one that you can download from CodePlex (2.0 alpha) should support Windows 8.1 Flyout. I have been using it and it's pretty stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the new CM release (alpha 2) fixed the issue, so I'm adding some more information here to help other newcomers like me. Here is what I'm doing now:

In app's `Configure` I have some bootstrap code like:

```
...
ResourceLoader loader = ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse("Resources");
ISettingsService settings = _container.RegisterSettingsService();
settings.RegisterFlyoutCommand<ContentSettingsViewModel>(loader.GetString("SettingsContent"));
```

The `ContentSettingsViewModel` is a viewmodel for filtering some contents. The string got from resources is the label which will appear in the settings flyout (be sure there is an entry for this string, as passing an empty or null string triggers an exception). This VM is derived from CM `Screen` as I'm overriding `OnActivate` and `OnDeactivate` to load and save settings when the user opens or dismisses the settings page.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't ready to move to the alpha version of CM, you can update Callisto to 1.4.0 via NuGet.  That fixed the error for me.